# Clojure list leiningen namespaces

Tags: reflection, clojure, leiningen

Incanter, a graphing/plotting tool, works fine:

```
[incanter "1.5.6"] ; in project.clj
; in repl:
(do (use '(incanter core stats charts)) (view (histogram (sample-normal 1000))))
```

But how can I programmatically list namespaces from leiningen-dependencies?
all-ns does not work:

```
; comes up empty UNTILL you (use 'incanter.charts):
(filterv #(.contains % "charts") (mapv str (all-ns)))
```

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`(all-ns)` returns only namespaces that has been already loaded (directly or indirectly, e.g. by using `require` or `use`).

For searching not-yet-loaded namespaces you can use [`tools.namespace`](https://github.com/clojure/tools.namespace) and functions from its [`clojure.tools.namespace.find`](http://clojure.github.io/tools.namespace/#clojure.tools.namespace.find) namespace.